# React remove extra question mark in push history

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use this code:

```
getProvince = (e, {value}) => {
    this.props.history.push({
        pathname: '/Search' + window.location.search,
        search: window.location.search ? '&Province=' + value : 'Province=' + value
    })
}
```

URL:

```
/Search?Province=1
```

And:

```
getCity = (e, {value}) => {
    this.props.history.push({
        pathname: '/Search' + window.location.search,
        search: window.location.search ? '&City=' + value : 'City=' + value
    })
}
```

URL:

```
/Search?Province=1?&City=2

------------------^
```

To add new parameter (query string) to current url, but as you see, it add an extra `?` question mark to url and it break route, I want this output:

```
/Search?Province=1&City=2
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

try this : `window.location.search.replace("?" , "")` when adding new parameter to current URL